# Regular expression to split "word-operator-number"

Tags: regex

I need to split the `season>=2015` into `season`, `>=`, and `2015`. I am using this.

```
(?<=[-+*/])|(?=[-+*/])
```

I'm new to regex. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: `(?<=\W)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?=\W)`

Comment: You should define a bit more closely what your expected valid inputs can be, because if you don't, the best answer to your question is `(season)(>=)(2015)`.

Comment: what language you are using?

Comment: Why are you looking for these `[-+*/]` while you need to split on `>=`?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the 3 tokens in 3 separate groups:

```
([A-Za-z]+)(\W+)(\d+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/t8NPE7/1

Comment: but that will not be splitting. What if you have a long string with various of this in it?? You cannot capture all the parts... You have to split

Comment: Not sure where in the OP's description he implies he has several instances of his example input in his actual input. Until he actually says so I would lean on the side that he doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For splitting `season>=2015` into `season`, `>=` and `2015` you can exploit the fact that they are separated by word boundaries and hence split them using `\b`. Following is the code you can use,

```
String text = "season>=2015";
String[] data = text.split("\\b");
Arrays.stream(data).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which prints,

```
season
>=
2015
```

Comment: you are missing the `>=` part. You should also have it. check OP expected output

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:

`([A-Za-z]*)(\D+)(\d+)`

explanation:

- `([A-Za-z]+)` matches everything before the operator
- `(\D+)`  matches the operator
- `(\d+)` matches number

[try at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rYPIs3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern: `(\w+)([=><]{1,2})(\w+)`.

First capturing group `(\w+)` will match one or more word characters - this will capture everything before operator.

Second capturing group `([=><]{1,2})` will match operators.

Third capturing group `(\w+)` will match everything on the other side of the operator.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OW1tYM/1)

Alternatively, you could use this pattern: `([^=><]+)([=><]{1,2})(.+)`.

First capturing group `([^=><]+)` will match everything except operator.

Rest is more or less the same :)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OW1tYM/2)